# Convert the PHP code using mysqli()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

### Convert the following PHP code using mysqli().

The following code don`t work in php 7 and i do not know how to use mysqli(). So, can anyone help to change the following code using mysqli().

---

The following code is for  connecting the database for adding answer for forum. Here, i am trying to connect with my local server using xampp and select database(here, db_name = "test1"). Then i am trying to Get value of id that sent from hidden field and Find highest answer number.After that it will add + 1 to highest answer number and keep it in variable name "$Max_id" and if there no answer yet set it = 1.Then it will again get values that sent from form and create date and time.After that it will Insert answer.If added new answer, add value +1 in reply column at last the connection will be close.

```
   <?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username=""; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="test1"; // Database name
$tbl_name="forum_answer"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.


mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Get value of id that sent from hidden field
$id=$_POST['id'];

// Find highest answer number.
$sql="SELECT MAX(a_id) AS Maxa_id FROM $tbl_name WHERE question_id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);

// add + 1 to highest answer number and keep it in variable name "$Max_id". if there no answer yet set it = 1
if ($rows) {
$Max_id = $rows['Maxa_id']+1;
}
else {
$Max_id = 1;
}

// get values that sent from form
$a_name=$_POST['a_name'];
$a_email=$_POST['a_email'];
$a_answer=$_POST['a_answer'];

$datetime=date("d/m/y H:i:s"); // create date and time


// Insert answer
$sql2="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(question_id, a_id, a_name, a_email, a_answer, a_datetime)VALUES('$id', '$Max_id', '$a_name', '$a_email', '$a_answer', '$datetime')";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);

if($result2){
echo "Successful<BR>";
echo "<a href='view_topic.php?id=".$id."'>View your answer</a>";


// If added new answer, add value +1 in reply column
$tbl_name2="forum_question";
$sql3="UPDATE $tbl_name2 SET reply='$Max_id' WHERE id='$id'";
$result3=mysql_query($sql3);

}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}

// Close connection

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, asking people to write a code for you is off topic here.

Comment: I am not telling people to write the whole  code here . I am telling people to tell me what should i change  and where should I change.

Comment: you should change mysql functions. Anywhere. Hope it is clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//DB Connection
$dbserver    = "...";
$dbusername  = "...";
$dbpassword  = "...";
$db          = "...";

//create Connnection
$conn = new mysqli($dbserver, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $db);

//check Connection
if($conn->connect_error)
{
    die("connection failed: ".$conn->connect_error);
}
```

AND

```
$sql="";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Change to

```
$sql = "";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

also note the

```
mysql_close();
```

Comment: To close the connection

Comment: mysqli_close($conn);  should be use or mysql_close(); should be use.